# Custom rest api endpoint response json problem

Tags: rest-api, json, endpoints

I am using WP 4.6 which the rest api have not yet included in the core. But I still can use `rest_api_init` to create an api endpoint. The problem is how can I change the endpoint response into proper json format?

This is what I did.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'news/v1', '/latest', array(
    'methods' => "GET",
    'callback' =>'get_latest_posts_api',
  ) );
} );

function get_latest_posts_api($data ){
    $data = array(
                   'title' => 'test title',
                   'content' => 'blah blah blah......'
    );
   return  rest_ensure_response($data);
}
```

When I call the endpoint in another wp site, I got nothing.

```
$recent_posts = wp_remote_get("http://xxxx.com/wp-json/news/v1/latest/");
$i = 1;

print_r(json_decode($recent_posts['body'], true));//this give me nothing
 echo $recent_posts['body']; //this give me the raw data though.
```

When I open directly on firefox, it shows me `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

What is the problem?

**UPDATE**

I added data array to be returned, but still got the error.

**UPDATE**

Debug using `json_last_error()` on decoding the response and it gave me `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` error. But I don't get it, I thought the `register_rest_route` already handle converting to json?

I also tried with json encoding in the callback function, still got me this error.

I am lost.

Comment: Do you need to decode the `body`? You probably should decode the whole JSON response and then echo what you need.

Comment: @JackJohansson I tried, nothing come out.

Comment: Adding the content of `$recent_posts` to your question can help us understand the problem better. Right now, it's unclear to me.

Comment: @JackJohansson, I added sample data in the endpoint function, still got the error.

Comment: No I meant add the content of that variable to your _"question"_, by using the [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/278776/edit) link so we can investigate the issue.

Comment: @JackJohansson, thanks for the quick reply, I just check the error by `json_last_error()` during decoding, found that it was the Json format is not valid.  But I still don't know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out it is caused by a BOM character from one of my included file. If you are having same problem, you can save your file to Encode in UTF8 without BOM.